# Can't return a pointer in CUDA

Tags: c, pointers, cuda

For some reason this code seems to work;

```
bool * copyHostToDevice(bool * h_input, size_t numElems)
{
    bool * d_output;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_output, numElems*sizeof(bool));  
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy((void *)d_output,(void *)h_input,numElems*sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    return d_output;
}
```

But this generates an error:

```
bool * copyDeviceToHost(bool * d_input, size_t numElems)
{
    bool * h_output;
    cudaMalloc((void **) &h_output, numElems*sizeof(bool));  
    cudaMemcpy((void *)h_output,(void *)d_input, numElems*sizeof(bool),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    return h_output;
}
```

I'm running this remotely, in the udacity class on Parallel Programming.

The output when you call the second function is:

> We are unable to execute your code. Did you set the grid and/or block size correctly?
>
> Your code compiled!

So its getting a runtime error.  When I remove pieces of the 2nd fcn, it becomes clear that the error is being generated by the cuaMemcpy() call.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second code you are using `cuda_malloc` to allocate `h_output` and passing it to a device-to-host copy as a host pointer. That is wrong, `h_output` should be a host pointer. You code should look something like this:

```
bool * copyDeviceToHost(bool * d_input, size_t numElems)
{
    bool * h_output;
    h_output = (bool *)malloc(numElems*sizeof(bool));  
    cudaMemcpy((void *)h_output,(void *)d_input, numElems*sizeof(bool),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    return h_output;
}
```

ie. use a host memory allocation routine (`malloc`, C++ `new`, perhaps even `cudaMallocHost` if you wanted pinned host memory) not a device memory allocation API.